# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00984: column not allowed here

Tags: java, oracle, web

I am facing a problem while inserting data using a web form into my table. I am using a session attribute which when inserted into the table will also act as a foriegn key to another table. I have typed the same code into my sql command prompt and everything seems to work fine but the problem only persist when i use in the java web format. I have made sure that there are no typo's present.But still facing the same problem

```
<%@page import="storage.data"%>
<%
        String fn,un,ln,mb,em,sug;

         fn=request.getParameter("uname");
         //ln=request.getParameter("lname");
         mb=request.getParameter("mobno");
         em=request.getParameter("email");
         sug=request.getParameter("sugg");

         data dt=new data();

           out.println(fn+mb+em+sug);

           try{

                dt.st=dt.cn.createStatement();
                out.println("1");
                String insert="insert into feedback_user values(myseqfeed.nextval,'"+ session.getAttribute("regid").toString() +"','"+fn+"',"+em+","+Integer.parseInt(mb)+",'"+sug+"')";
                out.println("2");
                dt.st.executeUpdate(insert);
                out.println("3");
                    //response.sendRedirect("user_feedback.jsp?sub=1");
            }
            catch(Exception ex){
            out.println(ex);
            }
%>
```

Comment: What's the actual SQL command being executed when the error happens?  If Oracle says there's an error, there's an error, regardless of how many times you've checked your code.

Comment: It's always a good idea to specify columns when inserting data.

Comment: Your `em` parameter, which represents an email, is unquoted in the resulting `SQL` statement.

Comment: +1 on the `em` parameter being unquoted.  Also, you should be using a `PreparedStatement` for this.  Everytime you run your statement with a given set of parameters, as you have it, you will be sending a completely new SQL statement to Oracle.  With normal database parameter settings, this means Oracle will have to spend time parsing the statement (slow) and latch (i.e., lock) key resources while doing so (not scalable).  Also, it means you'll fill your library cache with lots of duplicate SQLs, meaning other SQLs are likely to get pushed out of the cache, requiring them to reparse more often.

Comment: please use a prepared statement and parameters. your code as is has a sql injection vulnerability. Also instead of printing 2. print the insert variable, that will give you your answer.